# F10 key, what is this, that it's doing on my PC?

Tags: function-keys

Please look at this image: [Unkown Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDLWR.png). What is this in middle? It's slide bar has length of 3 (picture shows length 2), which changes when I press F10 (from 0 to 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is keyboard backlight intensity. With this on, you should be able to see keys in keyboard even in darkness.

Comment: I don't have backlight keyboard, lol.

Comment: That's an issue to take up with your hardware vendor.